# In App Billing V3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an issue with In App Billing. I am using the helper class from the TrivialDrive sample.
Here is how I implement it.

1. User presses Remove Ads
2. Start Helper
3. Use Listener to detect when helper is setup.
4. Query Inventory
5. Use Listener to detect when complete
6. Check whether purchase has already been made. If so remove ads and exit
7. If not then launchPurchaseFlow to purchase.

This works fine on one device, however if a user buys on one device then attempts it on another device the second device works as follows:

The helper sets up as normal, then when it checks inventory, it finds no item purchased (I understand there is a delay before this updates). It then attempts to purchase, but says item already bought on the Google play window. This would be fine if I could detect this in code, but it returns to the listener that the user canceled the purchase.

Is there a way to detect that the user has already bought the item using the `purchaseFinishedListener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the `handleActivityResult` method returns User Canceled

`else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            logDebug("Purchase canceled - Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));

            result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_USER_CANCELLED, "User canceled.");

            if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);

        }`

I added the line `if (responseCode==BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) result = new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED, "Success");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

```
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

    .....................

    if (inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_CONTENT)) {

        mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_CONTENT), null);
    }
}
```

};

Comment: I do not wish to consume the item, just to check whether it has been purchased. The query inventory reports item not bought (due to delay) but when I launchPurchaseFlow, it knows I have purchased as it says already bought. However this doesn't get returned to the listener, just that the user canceled the purchase

Comment: dont use the consume code...just take sku detals from this code and use it as you want

Comment: But if I use this code, the purchase has not been bought due to delay